# the structure of persistence modules

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-data-analysis

I am reading the book *The Structure and Stability of Persistence Modules*. In chapter 2 it's told that under some conditions, a persistence module can be expressed as a direct sum of interval modules, and this decomposition is unique. Then the book gives example (2.10): [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeIsP.png), [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBW25.png).

I am confused about the decomposition here. For example, I don't know at the point $c$, why $b$ must be the one that is killed rather than $a$, and why the decomposition can not be :

$H_0(X_{sub})=k[a,c)\oplus k[b,+\infty)\oplus k[d,e)$

or

$H_0(X_{sub})=k[a,c)\oplus k[b,e)\oplus k[d,+\infty)$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer here is the following.
Note that in the persistence module $H_0(X_{sub})$, the map $H_0(X_a)\to H_0(X_f)$, i.e. from index $a$ to index $f$, has rank one.
However, in either the module $k[a,c)\oplus k[b,+\infty)\oplus k[d,e)$ or the module $k[a,c)\oplus k[b,e)\oplus k[d,+\infty)$, the rank of the map from index $a$ to index $f$ is zero.
Hence $H_0(X_{sub})$ cannot be isomorphic to either $k[a,c)\oplus k[b,+\infty)\oplus k[d,e)$ or $k[a,c)\oplus k[b,e)\oplus k[d,+\infty)$.

Indeed, it instead turns out that the persistence module $H_0(X_{sub})$ is isomorphic to $k[a,+\infty)\oplus k[b,c)\oplus k[d,e)$; Gabriel's theorem says it can be isomorphic to exactly one such decomposition into indecomposables (up to reordering of the indecomposable factors).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! But I am a bit confused about why the linear map $H_0(X_a)->H_0(X_f)$ must have rank one. For example, if we set all the map $h$ during the filtration as: $h(x)=0$, they are still linear, but the rank is always zero. There is no constrain on the form of linear map in the Gabriel's theorem, so I guess for any reasonable linear map, we can get the same decomposition, but it seems not in this case.

Comment: The fact that the linear map $H_0(X_a)\to H_0(X_f)$ has rank one is coming from the first figure from the book that you linked to above. Here the sublevelset $X_a$ is a single point at the bottom of the curve, and the sublevelset $X_f$ is the entire curve. The inclusion of a single point into a (larger) connected component induces an isomorphism on $H_0$, simply because that single point is also a generator for $H_0$ of the larger connected component.